# I have a issue with creating a book class in c#

Tags: c#

Okay so I have to create a class called book and it has to have an author, title and a date and I have to add a method in at the end called display() that outputs the title and author. I think I have the right code but it keeps giving me an error with the date?

```
   namespace lab7_feador
  {
     class Program
  {
         static void Book(string[] args);

            public class Book
 {
    public string Nick { get; set; }
    public string James { get; set; }
    public string Radar { get; set; }
    public int 1989 { get; set; }



              }
         }
    }
```

is this how it is supposed to be?

or does it look like this I just need to add the date

namespace lab7_feador
{

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       book;

        book = title book ("Radars adventure");
        Console.WriteLine(book.title());

        book = Author ("Nick James");
        Console.WriteLine(author.Describe());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

    class book
    {
        private string title;

        public book(string title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

         public string Describe()
         {
          return "The name of this book is " + title;
         }

        public string Color
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What date would that be and what is the error message?

Comment: `public int 1989 { get; set; }`?  oh boy...

Comment: The best advice I can give is that you talk to your fellow classmates, and (re-)read the chapter on class design and properties of your curriculum.

Comment: Your class properties should not be named as values.  For example, instead of string Nick, you should have string Forename. Instead of int 1989 you should have DateTime PublishedDate

Comment: Your code is quite weird. Usually class describes a set of objects and not a particular object. What you want to achive?

Comment: You probably should also look at why you are using nested classes.  I would suggest you search for some C# introduction videos.  There are a few basic issues with your code that can be fixed with a little effort.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your class is called Program.  You want a class called Book:

```
class Book {}
```

2) You have properties Nick, James, Radar and "1989".  You want properties Title, Author and Date.

```
public string Author {get;set;}
public string Title {get;set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
```

3) You were getting an error with the date.  There is no date, only an integer property called 1989 (which is an invalid property name).  1989 is more likely the value of the year of the date than the name of the property.

I won't provide a full solution here, as this looks very homeworky - but take a look at this tutorial; it should help you solve this problem: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Date then you should use DateTime type, also you cannot display the date directly.
Do something like this, and assign when you are creating an instannce of your object,

Your class will be:

```
   public class Book
   {
     public string Property1 { get; set; }
     public string Property2 { get; set; }
     public string Property3 { get; set; }
     public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
   }
```

Assign values like this,

```
   Book bookObj = new Book();
   bookObj.Property1 = "Nick";
   bookObj.Property2 = "James";
   bookObj.Property3 = "Radar";
   bookObj.SomeDate = new DateTime(1989, 01, 01);
```

Comment: that's just how I thought it should be done if there is a more knowledgeable way I would like to know I don't want it to be weird ha and yes im sorry I should have included the error

Comment: @coleenfeador You mean you want to set default value?

Comment: yeah like I want it to say the author and title and date if that makes sense and when I tried the date it has the red error line under it and also I didn't know I was using the wrong code?

Comment: I re did it with another code does that look better?